# Does JavaScript have an expression form of switch?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, ternary-operator

When getting a value conditionally, I like to use the ternary operator (`?:`) so that I can have `const` variable declarations:

```
// Better
const foo = x ? 'bar' : 'goo';

// Worse
var foo;
if (x) {
    foo = 'bar';
} else {
    foo = 'goo';
}
```

I would like to do the same for `switch` statements. I can use a series of nested `?:`, but this is quite cumbersome and does not scale well:

```
const foo = x === 1 ? 'bar' : (x === 2 ? 'goo' : 'zoo');
```

I could even use a closure, but this is also verbose:

```
const foo = (() => {
  switch(x) {
    case 1: 
        return 'bar';
    case 2: 
        return 'goo';
    default:
        return 'zoo';
  }
})();
```

Is there a `switch` *expression* in JavaScript?

Comment: OP means an **expression**

Comment: If you're asking if JavaScript has something for switches the same if-statements have the ternary operator, I don't think any language does.

Comment: @DrewKennedy I haven't seen it yet either

Comment: If you are trying to cram more than two or three conditions and values onto the same line… you're probably better off using an actual `switch` to write *clean, readable code*. There's no inherent advantage in being able to squeeze everything into one line.

Comment: @deceze Put this up as an answer and you get a vote from me because you're absolutely right.

Comment: You can use a function containing an ES2015 `Map` and property look ups to mimic a switch statement.

Comment: There is a proposal for "do expressions" which would fit this use-case. Unfortunately it's [still at stage 0](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/stage-0-proposals.md), although it is supported by Babel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR: There is no such expression

### The ternary is possible

The way you have done is with the ternary would be the correct approach in this case. But as you could see, it indeed does not scale well.

### But using a function seems better

A fix would be to use a function that returns you a value.

```
  function getSomething(input)
  {
     if(input == 1)
         // return for case 1
     if(input == 2)
         // return for case 2
      ...
  }
```

Comment: @LUH3417 No problem :-)

Comment: This is interesting: `if/else` statements combined with functions are as expressive as switch statements, but they are not equivalent due to function scope/block scope.

Answer (score 4):

You should first and foremost keep things readable and manageable. Squeezing two or three conditions with four or five values into one line is unreadable almost any way you turn it.

I'd suggest this very declarative approach:

```
let fooToBarMap = {
    foo: 'bar',
    baz: 42
};

let y = fooToBarMap[x] || 'default';
```

Comment: With the caveat that this doesn't work if any of the values are falsey. But it's not a problem if they're constants or you otherwise know they're always truthy.

Comment: Please note that with object literals you can match prototype properties too and it works only for `String`s. Rather use a `Map`.

Comment: All valid concerns, but those are really edge cases I'd think, and are easy to mitigate if you hit one of them.

Comment: It's also possible to do a one-liner: `const result = { foo: 'bar', baz: 42 }[input] || 'default'`. Readability not guaranteed.

Comment: @gcampbell DID YOU LISTEN TO ANYTHING I SAID!? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

No. The logically equivalent expression would be either a nested ternary operator, as you've listed, or a similarly unwieldy construct of boolean operands.

Comment: @JordiCastilla - Please reread the question and use your question marks more sparingly.  :)

Answer (score 0):

When it is not too long I like to use `||` and `&&` for this purpose.

```
const foo = (x === 1 && 'bar') || (x === 2 && 'goo') || 'zoo'
```

Comment: This is not the equivalence of a switch but of an `if/else` statement

Comment: @LUH3417 and what is a switch? :)

Comment: That answer doesn't change the facts, actually it just legittimates more my statement

Comment: When `x` were a function and you want to pass its return value to your expression, how would you solve this without 1) applying `x()` several times and 2) don't use an additional variable?